# Is it at least theoretically possible for an electron and an antimuon or antitauon to annihilate?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, weak-interaction, leptons

In other words, can mismatched particles and antiparticles react with each other?  What about an up quark and anti-down quark?

Answer (score 6):

A left-handed up quark and a left-handed anti-down quark can annihilate into a W boson because of the nature of the weak interactions. Right-handed quarks do not interact via W boson because W boson is only left-handed, so they will not annihilate each other.

On the other hand, electron and an anti-muon **can not** annihilate each other in tree level because it would violate lepton number conservation. They can interact via a W boson but also an electron neutrino and a muon anti-neutrino would be created in the process.

There are some Grand Unification theories that allow lepton number violation and predict a rare process of annihilating electrons and muons into some new kind of bosons.

Comment: Why not exchange a neutrino in the t-channel?  The electron could couple to W and an electrino, which would convert to a muino in flight, thanks to the PMNS mixing terms.  It would be feeble effect, given the short life of a virtual neutrino, but ...

Comment: What are electrino and muino?

Comment: Neutrinos come in three distinct flavors or generations, which are the isospin partners of the electron, muon, and tauon, respectively -- just as in the quark zoo, U partners with D, C with S, and T with B.  The PMNS matrix is the leptonic counterpart to the CKM matrix for quarks.

Comment: I know that. My question was about the terms, electrino and muino, that you have used in your comment. Are they different than electron neutrino and muon neutrino, respectively? Or just a short-hand naming?

Comment: Just short-hand.

Comment: OK. So, regarding your comment: the annihilation is a process that happens at the same spacetime point. If an electron and an anti-muon annihilated to a boson, say $A$, you need to have an operator in your Lagrangian involving $$g \psi_e (x) \gamma^\alpha \psi_\mu (x) A_\alpha (x)$$ where g is the coupling constant, $\psi_e$ and $\psi_\mu$ are the electron and muon annihilation field operators, $A_\alpha$ is the boson creation field operator, and $\gamma^\alpha$ are the Dirac matrices. Note that they all operators of the same spacetime point, x.

Comment: On the other hand, the t-channel exchange of neutrino with an oscillation is impossible due to the fact that these oscillations happens after the neutrino travels at least 1-2 km.

Comment: I said it would be a feeble effect, but maybe not as feeble as you think.  Look up the mixing angles in the PMNS matrix.

Comment: As for you previous comment on the semantics of "annihilation", your definition is simply too narrow.  I'd call it wrong.

Comment: It is not my definition, it is the definition of quantum field theory.

Comment: $e\bar{e}\to 2\gamma $ is also a t-channel process with a virtual electron running between the two vertices, but people call it electron-positron annihilation even though it does not fit your definition of incoming particles going pfft at one and the same vertex.  
The mixing element in the neutrino mass matrix is of order ${{m}_{\nu }}$.  Thus, the amplitude for $e\bar{\mu }\to {{W}^{+}}{{W}^{-}}$ is suppressed by a factor of order $m_{\nu }^{2}/t\sim {{({{m}_{\nu }}/{{m}_{W}})}^{2}}$, where *t* is the Mandelstam variable.  Call it ultra-feeble if you like, but not impossible.

Comment: The amplitude would be $$\sim \left| U_{e3}U^*_{\mu3} \frac{m^2_{\nu_3}}{m_W^2} \right|^2$$ where $U_{\ell \nu}$ is the PMNS matrix element. So this amplitude is $<10^{-52}$, which is so much beyond observable limits. If you could observe such a scattering, it would mean that not only you would observe new physics, but also observe something beyond neutrino oscillations. Because an oscillation period giving such a huge precision in time should imply a huge uncertainty in energy which would not be the case for a high precision calorimeter.

Comment: Your expression looks correct at a quick glance, but it's the square of an amplitude.  You are being pointlessly argumentative.  The OP asked "is it theoretically possible ..."  Yes indeed, there is a process that can do it, but the effect (although nonzero)  is too small to detect.  Please drop the subject.  I am tired of replying.

Comment: You don't have to reply. My answer to "theoretically to annihilate?" is no, and to "theoretically to interact?" is that it is so rare that it can not be falsified in current experiments. Any observation would imply a new physics, thus a new theoretical model. [Yes, you are right: I have calculated the square of the amplitude but written it is amplitude, sorry for the typo, however it does not change the conclusion].

Comment: Dear Oktay (Turkish name?), if an up quark and anti-down quark annihilate, doesn't that violate baryon number conservation?

Comment: Dear Kurt (yes, Turkish name). Up quark has baryon number 1/3, an anti-down quark has a baryon number -1/3 so the annihilation of each other (to a W boson) would make baryon number $0$. A bound state of them would make the total baryon number zero, as well, which we call a pi meson.