# Why $\mu^++e^-\rightarrow \gamma +\gamma$ not possible?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

An electron and a $\mu^+$ bound by the Coulomb attraction is  called *muonium*. Consider the following decay
$$\mu^++e^-\rightarrow \gamma +\gamma $$
I'm reading An Introduction to Nuclear Physics by Greenwood, it says the following decay is not possible. But Why?

As far I can see all the conservation laws are followed by the above decay. Even the conservation of lepton number. There are two lepton on the left side, one electron and another anti muon that add up to $0$ and there are no leptons on the right-hand side.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/403834

Comment: There is electron lepton number and muon lepton number and also a tau lepton number. they are seperate conservation laws and don't add up like this.

Comment: @Pete If so then $$\mu^++e^-\rightarrow e^-+e^++\nu_e+\bar{\nu}_\mu$$ should not possible?

Comment: That is how muons do decay.

Comment: I understood! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Pete Hold on... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton_number ("Lepton flavor is only **approximately** conserved"), and see the first two paragraphs in the introduction of [arXiv:1303.4097](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.4097) ("In the last decade a variety of neutrino oscillation experiments proved beyond any doubt that neutrino flavors, i.e., individual lepton flavor numbers, are **not** conserved.") Actually, even *total* lepton number is not strictly conserved in the standard model -- see page 454 in Weinberg's *The Quantum Theory of Fields*, vol 2 -- but that's a non-perturbative effect.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly As you pointed, lepton flavor violation has been observed in neutrino oscillations. But that is only in the case of the neutral sector. But still, there is no hint of lepton flavor violation in the charged sector. Only experimental limits are being put on such lepton flavor violating processes in the charged sector.  But in the current scenarios, the above decay should be violated in the Standard Model. Maybe with the inclusion of new physics the process may happen.